# How to shift a div container downward when another div containers of different sizes becomes visible

Tags: html

There are four div containers on a page with different sizes. Say-

```
div1 - <div id="id1" class="foo">   ---has a table inside it with 10 rows
div2 - <div id="id2" class="foo">   ---has a table inside it with 6 rows
div3 - <div id="id3" class="foo">   ---has a table inside it with 2 rows

div4 - <div id="fui">    --- has a text area and a submit button
```

be default, on page load div1, div2, div3 are `hidden` with below CSS and div 4 is always visible. Now based on some conditions, div1, div2, div3 becomes visible.

The problem I am facing is when any of div1,2,3 becomes visible, div4 doesn't shift downward relatively but overlaps and appears on the top of the visible div (any of div1,2,3). I want to shift div4 down relative to any of the appearing div1 or div2 or div3 above.

CSS -

```
.foo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100;
        left: 10;
        display: none;
    }


#fui {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%%;
        position: relative;
        left: 100;
        top: 400;
    }
```

to display div, i am using following code in java script -

```
style.display = 'inline-block';
```

Comment: Hint : Don't use `position: absolute;`

Comment: Awesome mate, I never thought that the other absolute was the culprit.